# Try to print "Hello World" on webpage but something happened

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner in Ruby on Rails.
Today, I want to have my first try to print "Hello World" on webpage but something happened.

First of all,I create a "project" folder by "mkdir project" and then create new rails project in this folder by "rails new demo".

Next,I type "rails server" and website shows good.

Then,I type "rails generate controller welcome" and put this code

```
Demo::Application.routes.draw do
get "welcome/say_hello" => "welcome#say"
# ...
end
```

into config/routes.rb .

Then, I run "rails server" again and some problem happened like below.

```
C:\project\demo>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000/
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load': C:/project/demo/config/routes.rb:59:
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from C:65535:in `execute_if_updated'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block intsort_each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels)in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from C:/project/demo/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/project/demo/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from C:/project/demo/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from C:/project/demo/config.ru:in `new'
    from C:/project/demo/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Is anyone know what happened??

This is my routes filr as below:

```
Demo::Application.routes.draw do
    get "welcome/say_hello" => "welcome#say"
    # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your routes file on `line 59`. You probably forgot to add a `do` keyword to a block, or forgot to close a block by using an `end` keyword.

Show us your routes file in order to debug the problem more accurately.

See this line in the stack trace:

```
load': C:/project/demo/config/routes.rb:59: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

Comment: Thank you Mohamad, I found there is a extra "end" on line 59.